# SMS with alphanumeric sender discarded

Tags: sms-blocking

I am working in a company where we host a server to send SMS to mobile phone providers. We have several customers each day who cannot receive SMS we deliver to them because their Android SMS app discards them due to an alphanumeric sender. So, we have the "Delivered to Phone" state from the SMSC, but the customer effectively does not see the message.

We manage lists of customers who need plain numeric senders and circumvent the problem in this way.

Is there a way that might be a possible solution for - at least a good number of - the customers to easily setup their app or phone to accept/allow alphanumeric senders so we can tell them? Note, however that our customers are any average mobile phone customers, not necessarily with any informatic knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I give the answer myself. If you find out how to activate it (which is quite easy because the web is full of it), you also know how to deactivate it.

Sorry for the stupid question.